# Classification or Clustering Techniques Apply on Stack Exchange Data dump

Tags: cluster-analysis, classification

I want to apply some clustering or classification techniques on Stack Exchange Data dump, But i don't know, how to do this ?

What data parameter i used for classification/clustering techniques?
How to extract those parameters from the data?

Is there any research paper that are published about "implementation of Classification or clustering techniques on Stack Exchange Data dump"?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point about classification, clustering, data science and such in general is **to try out different things**.

So don't try to shortcut and get a prepared solution. The *way* is the solution, and you should really try to find your own way.

Comment: Dear Mousse, i am not getting a shortcut for a solution, i just need help in a abstract way, that how we extract parameters from a data? "Is there any example"

Comment: Well, look at the data, it's XML. Extract whatever parts appear to be interesting to you, and for what you want to do *exactly*.